# PHP Array Remove Duplicates - not Array_Unique

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array (fake data) in PHP:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [pmkSuppliers] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [Name] => Supplier2
        [1] => Supplier2
        [Email] => Me@me.com2
        [2] => Me@me.com2
        [Address] => 624  st
        [3] => 624 st
        [Phone] => 900-111-1111
        [4] => 900-111-1111
        [Fax] => 900-111-1112
        [5] => 900-111-1112
        [TechSupport] => 900-111-1112
        [6] => 900-111-1112
        [Contact] => Greg
        [7] => Greg
        [Modified] => 2016-06-07
        [8] => 2016-06-07
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [pmkSuppliers] => 2
        [0] => 2
        [Name] => Nike
        [1] => Nike
        [Email] => me@none.com
        [2] => me@none.com
        [Address] => 4566 way
        [3] => 4566 way
        [Phone] => 901-206-5555
        [4] => 901-206-5555
        [Fax] => 901-206-5555
        [5] => 901-206-5555
        [TechSupport] => 901-206-5445
        [6] => 901-206-5445
        [Contact] => Brad
        [7] => Brad
        [Modified] => 2016-06-08
        [8] => 2016-06-08
    )

)
```

I want to remove all of the elements with a non int key. So it would look something like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => Supplier2
        [2] => Me@me.com2
        [3] => 624 st
        [4] => 900-111-1111
        [5] => 900-111-1112
        [6] => 900-111-1112
        [7] => Greg
        [8] => 2016-06-07
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => Nike
        [2] => me@none.com
        [3] => 4566 way
        [4] => 901-206-5555
        [5] => 901-206-5555
        [6] => 901-206-5555
        [7] => Brad
        [8] => 2016-06-08
    )

 )
```

I figure there has to be an easy way to do this, but I'm stuck. I can not use the PHP method **array_unique** because sometimes the values in my array are the same (like in the second set).

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Thanks,
FP

#### EDIT

This is how I have been doing it, but it seems crude.

```
foreach ($array as $insideArray) {
    foreach ($insideArray as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_int($key)) {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you fetching this using PDO?

Comment: you can try to use is_numeric+array_flip

Comment: @Thamilan Yes, in a roundabout way.

Comment: Then simply, change the fetch style to `PDO::FETCH_NUM`. Can I see your fetching code?

Comment: @SML I think your way would work, but I'm not sure it would be any more elegant/efficient than the way I have been doing it. (See my edit).

Comment: @Thamilan    

function select($query, $values = "") {

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);

        if (is_array($values)) {
            $statement->execute($values);
        } else {
            $statement->execute();
        }

        $recordSet = $statement->fetchAll();

        $statement->closeCursor();

        return $recordSet;
    }

Comment: why did you use echo $value, if you want your final output to be in the form of array?

Comment: @Fatpanda Try setting `$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);`

Comment: @SML Whoops, that was for testing purposes. Your answer below is a better execution of my loops.

Comment: @Thamilan Sweet! Thanks. `$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Fatpanda That's fine, I have added that to answer, check it out

Comment: Perhaps you should look into editing the title, as this has nothing to do with removing duplicate more like removing row based on criteria ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using PDOs, just set the fetch style:

```
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

You can see the difference fetchStyle in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

---

In addition, you can also use

```
$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Here is an external [article 1](http://hirengprajapati.blogspot.in/2012/09/php-pdo-fetch-methods.html) and [article 2](http://blog.encodez.com/blog/using-pdofetchall-examples-with-codes-and-output-results) that discusses, different fetch methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as &$arr){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!is_int($key)) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```